# I cant seem to fix these erros in my code

Tags: python

My assignment is asking me to:

Write a program to fetch employee name and the salary. Calculate the Federal tax and state tax based on the following criteria: If the salary is greater than 100000 then calculate the federal tax at 20% otherwise calculate the federal tax at 15% Calculate the state tax at 5% Calculate the net salary of the employee. To calculate the net salary, subtract federal and state tax from the gross salary.

I have written a program to solve this and it does run/ calculate everything my instructor asked, but I keep getting the same errors, every time I think I've fixed them.

Here is my code:

```
your_name = input('Please enter your name:')
employee_salary = int(input('Please enter your salary:'))
if employee_salary >= 100000:
    federal_tax = (employee_salary *20) / 100
    state_tax = (employee_salary * 5) / 100
    net_salary = employee_salary - state_tax - federal_tax
    print('Your Federal Tax is:'+str(federal_tax))
    print('Your State Tax is:'+str(state_tax))
    print('Your net salary is:'+str(net_salary))
else:
    employee_salary < 100000
    federal_tax = (employee_salary * 15) / 100
    state_tax = (employee_salary * 5) / 100
    net_salary = employee_salary - state_tax - federal_tax
    print('Your Federal Tax is:'+str(federal_tax))
    print('Your State Tax is:'+str(state_tax))
    print('Your net salary is:'+str(net_salary))
```

sorry if any of this looks messy, this if my first use of stackoverflow

Thank You!

[My code errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDgdd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the difference between the correct output and your output, your output is not formatted correctly. Include a space before every colon (`:`) in every `print` statement

Answer (score 0):

According to the test case's output and your output, the only difference is the space you are missing in the print statement.

Try below in every print statement:

```
print('Your Federal Tax is :'+str(federal_tax))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just alter the indentations and spacings.I think your grader throws output for spaces.
    `your_name = input('Please enter your name :')
    employee_salary = int(input('Please enter your salary :'))
    if employee_salary >= 100000:
        federal_tax = (employee_salary)*0.2
        state_tax = (employee_salary)*0.5
        net_salary = employee_salary -(state_tax + federal_tax)
        print('Your Federal Tax is :'+str(federal_tax))
        print('Your State Tax is :'+str(state_tax))
        print('Your net salary is :'+str(net_salary))
    else:
        employee_salary < 100000
        federal_tax = (employee_salary *0.15)
        state_tax = (employee_salary *0.05)
        net_salary = employee_salary -(state_tax + federal_tax)
        print('Your Federal Tax is :'+str(federal_tax))
        print('Your State Tax is :'+str(state_tax))
        print('Your net salary is :'+str(net_salary))`

Answer (score 0):

You'd better replace the `+` with a `,` on the `print` lines.

```
print("abc" + str(1)) # will print 'abc1'
print("abc", str(1))  # will print 'abc 1'
```

Using a comma will insert a space automatically.